# Typo3 Transform DB bodytext to frontend html

Tags: database, hyperlink, typo3

I try to import an old typo3 v4 into v10 and I'm using external_importer extension for the job. On the flow I would like to download the internal files like PDF and relink in bodytext.

The idea would be to transform the saved content to real html and evaluate the hyperlinks if are containing relative PDF links and in case trigger the download and rebuild the link to the file.

How would I proceed in this case?

I tried the following

```
    $parseObj = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ContentObjectRenderer::class);
    $html = $parseObj->stdWrap_HTMLparser($htmlStr, []);
    DebugUtility::debug($html);
```

but the hyperlink steel remains as <link http://someurl.com>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. If the solution is the same with mine, you are halfway there. You are missing the reference. Meaning, how should TYPO3 process the text. Here is what worked for me.

[TYPO3 render full t3:// links from bodytext in utility files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100409/typo3-render-full-t3-links-from-bodytext-in-utility-files/70100410#70100410)

First, use the `parseFunc` and not the `stdWrap_HTMLparser`. Then use this reference: `lib.parseFunc`. At the end you should have something like that:

```
$parseFuncTSPath = 'lib.parseFunc';
$html = $parseObj->parseFunc($htmlStr, [], '< ' . $parseFuncTSPath);
DebugUtility::debug($html);
```

And since you are using TYPO3 10, i would recommend to use DI (Dependency Injection). You can basically copy paste the code from the linked SO answer i pasted.

Best regards

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your Feedback. I just tried it does not seems to work in my case. I think the problem is that I missformatted my question. On import I have some links  in old record like `<link http://fileadmin/some.pdf _blank external "Titel">label</link >` this should be transformed to hyperlinks to can evaluate `href` value. I tried to extract this with regex but this could break on same cases

Comment: is this helpful? https://forge.typo3.org/issues/80903

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give a try.